# Is it possible to couple an odd number of Dirac fermions, at finite density, to a massless gauge field in 2+1d?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, parity, quantum-anomalies, chern-simons-theory

In a beautiful paper by A. N. Redlich (PRL $\bf{52}$, 18 (1984)) on the parity anomaly, the author indicates that an odd number of Dirac fermions can never be coupled to a massless gauge field in 2+1d due to the necessity of introducing background Chern-Simons terms to maintain gauge invariance

> "The induced topological term $\pm W[A]$ in $I_\mathrm{eff} [A]$ is known to produce a mass for the gauge fields.  Not only must parity conservation be violated in odd-dimensional theories with an odd number of fermions, but
>   the gauge fields *must* become massive as well",

where $W[A]$ is the Chern-Simons term and $I_\mathrm{eff} [A]$ the effective action obtained by integrating out the fermion degrees of freedom.

My question is whether this is still true if the fermions are at a finite density, i.e. one adds a chemical potential such that there is a whole Fermi surface of excitations (in this case, it's my understanding that one cannot simply integrate out the fermions to get $I_\mathrm{eff} [A]$). Is it possible to couple an odd number of Dirac fermions, at finite density, to a massless gauge field in 2+1d?